# I overstayed in South Africa and was banned. How long do I have to wait before I can re-enter the country?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, legal, south-africa

I overstayed my 90 day stay in South Africa by 2 days before leaving for Namibia. The officials wanted me to sign a one-year ban which I did not sign.

I now need to re-enter South Africa again only 24hours later. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you sure that you overstayed? You would have been informed when you exited South Africa how long you were banned from re-entering the country.

Comment: They wanted me to sign a 1year ban, that I, in the end never signed before I left.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you signed it or not.

Comment: You mean the ban is still valid then

Comment: I'm afraid so. You can try to return in one year.

Comment: And if I get a new passport

Comment: You're not the first person to try that! It doesn't work.

Comment: A ban from a country isn't a negotiation. It's not like they'll go "oh well she didn't sign the form, so we're stupefied now" and let you in. You overstayed and were banned. Why would they let you come back the next day?

Comment: I edited title and question body. Feel free to rollback if I misinterpreted your query.